# Harris - Combinatorics, Ballot - Solution verification

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I would like, if someone can verify whether my solution to this problem is correct.

> A ballot lists ten candidates for city council, eight candidates for the school board, and five bond issues. The ballot instructs voters to choose up to four people running for city council, rank up to three candidates for the school board, and approve or reject each bond issue. How many different ballots may be cast, if partially completed (or empty ballots are allowed)?

**Solution.**

Choosing upto $4$ people running for the city council $\rightarrow {10\choose4}+{10\choose3}+{10\choose2}+{10\choose1}+{10\choose0}$

Rank upto $3$ candidates for the school board $\rightarrow {P(8,3)+P(8,2)+P(8,1)+P(8,0)}$

Approve or reject upto $5$ bond issues $\rightarrow {2^0+2^1+2^2+2^3+2^4+2^5}$

The number of ballots that can be cast are,

$\left\{{10\choose4}+{10\choose3}+{10\choose2}+{10\choose1}+{10\choose0}\right\}\cdot\left\{{P(8,3)+P(8,2)+P(8,1)+P(8,0)}\right\}\cdot\\
\{2^0+2^1+2^2+2^3+2^4+2^5\}$

Comment: The language of the problem was slightly difficult for me, so I thought it best to verify.

Comment: "*If partially completed or empty ballots are allowed*" I would argue that the bond issue should instead be $3^5$ corresponding for each issue to be either *approve*, *reject*, or *leave blank*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with **JMoravitz** in the comments: the factor for the bond issues should be $3^5$, since on each of the $5$ issues a voter may vote *yes*, vote *no*, or not vote.

Your approach will also work, but only if you use it correctly. You cannot say, for instance, that there are $2^2$ possible ballots with $2$ bond issues voted on and $3$ left blank: there are $\binom52$ different pairs of bond issues that could be voted on, and each of these pairs can be voted on in $2^2$ different ways, so there are actually $\binom522^2$ ballots leaving exactly $3$ of the bond issues blank. Thus, your $2^0+2^1+2^2+2^3+2^4+2^5$ should actually be

$$\binom502^0+\binom512^1+\binom522^2+\binom532^3+\binom542^4+\binom552^5=\sum_{k=0}^5\binom5k2^k1^{5-k}=(2+1)^5=3^5$$

by the binomial theorem.

The other factors in your analysis are correct.

Comment: Ingenious, I wish I was able to connect the dots like that. To me, that's divine inspiration! I guess it just comes with practice. How do people become so good at Combinatorics?

Comment: @Quasar: Practice is a large part of it, though I think that it does come a bit more easily to some than to others.